# How to trigger JPanelMenu with Hammer.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I got JPanelMenu working on a button click, using the methodology described in the manual.
I am using two Hammer.JS actions on my mobile webapp, swipe right to return to the index page, and would like to use swipeleft to show the menu.

Here is the Hammer code, with the JPanelMenu trigger.
This does activate the menu, however, once the menu is closed, and then reopened with another swipe, the width of the menu appears to have doubled and filled with whitespace, the width increases with each subsequent activation.... Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var hammer = $('body').hammer();
    hammer.on('swipeleft', function(event) {
     var jPMx = $.jPanelMenu();
             jPMx.on();
             jPMx.trigger(true);
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: Sorted this, i think the instance which controlled the button to open the menu was conflicting, updated above

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out the `jPmx.on()` seemed to fix this, to allow both swipe and click a button to activate the menu.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var hammer = $('body').hammer();
hammer.on('swipeleft', function(event) {
 var jPMx = $.jPanelMenu();
    //   jPMx.on();
         jPMx.trigger(true);
});
 </script>
```